# erro mongodb getNextSequence is not defined

Tags: mongodb, auto-incremento

Bom dia, não estou conseguindo criar e executar essa função no mondodb 3.4
Estou seguindo esse tutorial: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

**Erro** 
Error:
ReferenceError: getNextSequence is not defined :@(shell):3:6

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true
      }
  );
return ret.seq;
 }
```

Quando executo esse comando no mongodb
Esta dando erro.

```
db.users.insert(
{
 _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
 name: "Sarah C."
}
)
```

**Failed to execute script.**

Error:
ReferenceError: getNextSequence is not defined :@(shell):3:6

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa salvar a função antes e depois carrega-lá, como sugeriu o @Cigano:

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "getNextSequence",
     value : function (name) { return x; }
   }
)
```

E depois:

```
db.loadServerScripts();
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente forçar o carregamento de funções da shell do MongoDB usando:

```
> db.loadServerScripts();
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.loadServerScripts/).